# How to avoid race conditions from client disconnections?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So, what I am doing right now is creating a new client object as new connections are received, and storing them within a self managed object; on user disconnect, I am removing the object. This is the basis of what it looks like:

```
var socketobj = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socketobj[socket.id] = socket;

    socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
        delete socketobj[socket.id];
    });
});
```

I am using each of these client objects to store extra information, such as  associated usernames etc. in the form of `socketobj[socket.id].user = username;`

The issue I am having is that a separate portion of my code will be running, and if the client disconnects just prior to the server accessing their client object, it will come up as undefined (because the object has just been deleted), and it will throw an exception.

How can I prevent this from happening? At the very minimum, how can I stop the errors from crashing my server everytime they are thrown?

Comment: socket.io has individual socket stores for this purpose, might be better suited than tacking arbitrary properties onto the socket, e.g `socket.set("username", "bromancer")`.  Also, if you use the redis backend, it comes with the added bonus that the store is accessible from different node instances.  If you're going to run more than one node, this approach will give you problems.

Comment: @numbers1311407 I am aware of this, but for my my purposes, a self-managed object is much more suitable; the actual code is nowhere near as simple as this.

Comment: You could always just delete the stored object after a timeout, rather than immediately.  Incidentally the redis store would do this out of the box.  Regardless, I'm not seeing the advantage in tacking arbitrary properties onto a business object which comes equipped with a `store` for exactly that purpose.

Comment: [actually the memorystore does this out of the box as well](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/stores/memory.js#L131)

Answer (score -2):

Ok, I didn't know it was event based not multithreaded, here's a new answer.

Just check if the entry exists before accessing it. If it does not, it just got deleted and you can do nothing/a different thing as is appropriate.

Comment: Node.js runs on only one thread; my issue is not that two threads are attempting to access it at the same time, because this is not how node works. The issue is that events are queued to attempt to read the variable even after it is deleted. Locking it would not solve this.

Comment: This is what I have been doing so far; it does work, but given the number of instances in which the object is accessed, it is requiring hundreds of 'if(socketobj[socket.id]){ //do code}, which is making for messy and unreadable code; I figure that there has to be a cleaner solution.